# SwiftUI Why can I return multiple views for PreviewProvider

Tags: swiftui

I noticed that I can do this:

```
struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    HomeView()
    HomeView()
    HomeView()
  }
}
```

The type is `some View`, which is a single view. Why can I return 3 `HomeView`s here? (I don't think this is inside a resultBuilder block because it's clearly a getter function body here, or am I wrong?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property has `ViewBuilder` wrapper, as declared:

```
public protocol PreviewProvider : _PreviewProvider {
    // ... other declarations here

    @ViewBuilder static var previews: Self.Previews { get }
```

And `ViewBuilder` can wrap here up to 10 different views, similarly as in any other place, ex. `View.body`.

Actually you should not think about concrete type in such case, but it will be rather

```
TupleView<(HomeView, HomeView, HomeView)>
```